# Reset form field is submitting form jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I'm new to jquery world and html5 coming over from Coldfusion. I have a simple form which submits correctly. I want the user to be able to clear the form WITHOUT submitting. With the code as it is, it DOES clear the data - but the form submits anyway. I just want it to stay put so the user has a clean slate to work with. I'm sure this is really simpled, but I just can't find it.

Code snippit is shown below.

```
<form class="comment_form" action="recordcomments.cfm" method="post" name="comment_form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">

      <label for="comments">Comment</label>
      <textarea name="comments" id="comments"></textarea>
      <cfoutput>
        <input type="hidden" value="#URL.TicketIdentifier#" Name="TicketIdentifier">
      </cfoutput>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">

      <button id="submit-comment" class="button icon-save c-success">Submit comment</button>
      <button id="reset-textbox" class="nobackground icon-ccw c-info">Reset text box</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>

</section>
</main>
</div>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="footer-meta col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <a href="http://lutherconsulting.com">
                            &copy; 2016, Luther Consulting, LLC</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <a class="icon-location c-inverse">10435 Commerce Drive, Suite 140, Carmel, IN 46032</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">Technical Support&nbsp;<a href="tel:866.517.6570" class="icon-phone c-inverse">866.517.6570, Option 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
</Cfif>
<br>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#window-close').click(function() {
        window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();
    });
    $('#submit-comment').click(function() {
        window.open('recordcomments.cfm', '_self');
    });
    $('#reset-textbox').click(function() {
        $('#comments').val('');
    });
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Use ajax on the submit event of the form and preventDefault to stop the page from changing - then add type=button: `<button type="button" ....`

Answer (score 0):

I hope following code will help you i try this code and it reset the form, so user can add new value.

```
 $('#reset-textbox').click(function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("comment_form").reset();
});
```

or this code also work for you.

```
  $('#reset-textbox').click(function() {
    $('.comment_form')[0].reset();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not even need javascript to achieve this.  It is already built into HTML natively...

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset text box" class="nobackground icon-ccw c-info" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be good to use jquery for this, since your `textarea` has an `id` of `id="comments";` give your input an `id` of `id="text";`

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#reset-textbox').click(function() {
     $('#comments').val('');
     $('#text').val('');
     });
</script>
```